# android 4.0 - Disabling apps on the device

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

One of the 4.0 features is Disabling Apps

Android Ice Cream Sandwich has a new feature that lets users disable practically any application they may want to, including those pesky carrier pre-installed apps that can strain device resources and drain battery even if you choose not to use them

I dont see this in the emulator and neither do i see any API for the same.

Can anyone help me here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is enabled in the emulator, though it's likely not where you'd expect to find it :)

Choose an app that's "preinstalled" (for this example, the browser works).
Drag it to the top of the screen where it says "App Info".
Release.
In the resulting screen, you'll be presented with two buttons near the top.  "Force Stop" and "Disable".

To answer the second part, currently there's no API for this feature.

EDIT:  To re-enable an application, go to Settings > Apps > "All" tab, scroll to the bottom.  Disabled apps will be labelled as such.  Just select the app, and click "Enable" where the disable button was before.

Comment: Where can i see the option to re enable it??

Comment: Updated to include how to re-enable :)

Answer (score 0):

Disabling an app from the Settings is available for all apps that are not signed with a platform keystore. The reason is that it tries to prevent the user from bricking their phone by not allowing disabling of apps signed with the system certificate and any launcher app in the system.